# No matching distribution found for py2neo==3.1.2 (from chat)

Tags: python, pip, chat

I was following [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gui-chat-application-using-tkinter-in-python/) tutorial and I was installing the dependencies but when I was installing "chat" it raised this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement py2neo==3.1.2 (from chat) (from versions: 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.1, 4.1.2, 4.1.3, 4.2.0, 4.3.0, 2020.0.0, 2020.1.0, 2020.1.1, 2021.0.0, 2021.0.1, 2021.1.0, 2021.1.1, 2021.1.2, 2021.1.3, 2021.1.4, 2021.1.5, 2021.2.0, 2021.2.1, 2021.2.2, 2021.2.3)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for py2neo==3.1.2 (from chat)
```

Any suggestions to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you tried to install `chat` by using `pip install chat`. However, the tutorial you linked is using a `chat.py` file, which you should create. The tutorial does not suggest to install `chat`.

By the way, the `chat` package seems to be a bit outdated according to its [release history](https://pypi.org/project/chat/#history): the last release was in mid-2018. So, the error you're seeing makes sense since py2neo switched to calendar versioning in 2020, and `chat` is requesting `3.1.2`, which confirms that this library was developed before 2020.

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me where the link for the chat.py file is?

Comment: It should be the server side script: "Server Side Script:  This script file name is ‘client.py'(say)."